# scheme calculate root of binary tree

Tags: scheme, binary-search-tree

So I am trying to write a function that will calculate the root of a binary tree in scheme. The root is calculated by the following criteria: the value at the root is the maximum of the values at its two children, where each of those values is the minimum for its two children, etc. Alternating between maximizing the children and minimizing the children.

so `(TREEMAX '((3 (2 5)) (7 (2 1)))` would return 3, because 5 is the max of 2 and 5. 3 is the minimum of 3 and 5. 2 is the max of 2 and 1. 2 is the min of 7 and 2. And finally to get root 3 is the max of 3 and 2. The code I have so far is as follows:

```
    (define TREEMAX
      (lambda (a)
        (cond ((list? (car a)) TREEMIN (car a))
              ((list? (cdr a)) TREEMIN (cdr a))
              ((> (car a) (cdr a)) (car a))
              (#t (cdr b)))))

    (define TREEMIN
      (lambda (a)
        (cond ((list? (car a)) TREEMAX (car a))
              ((list? (cdr a)) TREEMAX (cdr a))
              ((< (car a) (cdr a)) (car a))
              (#t (cdr b)))))
```

But my code is not returning the right number. Where could I be going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to run it yourself, by hand, using pen and paper? It's a very good way to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your description correctly, this should do:

```
(define (root lst (res null) (maxmin #t))
  (if (null? lst)
      (apply (if maxmin max min) res)
      (let ((c (car lst)))
        (root (cdr lst) 
              (cons (if (list? c) (root c null (not maxmin)) c) res)
              maxmin))))
```

then

```
> (root '((3 (2 5)) (7 (2 1))))
3
> (root '((3 (2 (1 5))) (7 ((2 7) 1))))
2
> (root '(1 2))
2
```

To see how it works, here's a version with a debugging `printf`:

```
(define (root lst (res null) (maxmin #t))
  (if (null? lst)
      (let* ((op (if maxmin max min)) (vl (apply op res)))
        (printf "~a ~a = ~a\n" op res vl)
        vl)
      (let ((c (car lst)))
        (root (cdr lst) 
              (cons (if (list? c) (root c null (not maxmin)) c) res)
              maxmin))))
```

which outputs, for your example:

```
#<procedure:max> (5 2) = 5
#<procedure:min> (5 3) = 3
#<procedure:max> (1 2) = 2
#<procedure:min> (2 7) = 2
#<procedure:max> (2 3) = 3
```

Answer (score -1):

When you apply the function `car` you use `(car a)` but when you apply the function `TREEMAX` you use `TREEMAX (car a)`?

The syntax of your code is wrong; you were unlucky that the errors are not flagged as syntax errors.  Here is a fix:

```
(define TREEMAX
  (lambda (a)
    (cond ((list? (car a)) (TREEMIN (car a)))
          ((list? (cdr a)) (TREEMIN (cdr a)))
          ((> (car a) (cdr a)) (car a))
          (else (cdr b))))
```

No idea if this solves your specific problem, but at least you'll be able to trust the computed value.